# Uninstall file in Start Menu applications list isn't always shown

Tags: nsis, uninstallation

After installing the application, the installer and uninstaller files are properly saved in the "install application folder" and in the "Start menu application folder" rispectively.

For example:
 - "install application folder" = "C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\"
 - "Start menu application folder" = "C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\"

Sometimes, though, the uninstaller file is not displayed into the application folder of the Start Menu Installed Applications List (list of installed Applications displayed on the left by pressing the Windows keyboard key).

Unfortunately I can't reproduce the problem. It doesn't appears each time I launch the Installer and I couldn't understand under which circumstances it appears.

Is there a possibility it can be solved by forcing a refresh of the Start Menu Installed Applications List? if this is the case, how can do it?

Thanks in advance to everyone for the possible help

EDIT: no solution but a workaround found here [Inno Setup Start menu uninstall shortcut is not shown on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48771335/10956787) 2nd answer

Comment: Can you add some code sample in the question? What macros do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 8 and 10 [hides shortcuts to uninstallers and help files on purpose](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190319-00/?p=102342), this is by design.

The Windows logo requirements says that you should only provide a single shortcut to your main application in the start menu. Only create multiple shortcuts if you have a suite of applications (like MS Office etc.). These guidelines have been in place for at least 20 years!

Comment: Thanks for the guideline. I will follow it and I will give the uninstall feature only from Control Panel. Regards