# How can I add/not add a shortcut to an uninstaller depending on the Windows version in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, shortcut, startmenu

According to

> [Inno Setup Start menu uninstall shortcut is not shown on Windows
> 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39371607/inno-setup-start-menu-uninstall-shortcut-is-not-shown-on-windows-10)

I should not add a shortcut to an uninstaller to the Start menu, on any version of Windows.
But still, can I somehow decide whether to create the shortcut or not depending on the version of Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Inno Setup section entries have [`MinVersion` and `OnlyBelowVersion` parameters](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=commonparams), which you can use to control on what [version of Windows](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=winvernotes) the entry gets used.

To create an icon on Windows below 8 only, use:

```
[Icons]
Name: "..."; Filename: "..."; OnlyBelowVersion: 6.2
```

---

*Though again, as the link says, do not clutter the Start menu with uninstall icons. They should not be there, no matter what version of Windows the user is using.*