# How to make Inno Setup create single shortcut/icon in Start menu instead of a folder (program group)

Tags: windows, inno-setup, startmenu

I want to make Inno Setup create a single application shortcut/icon in *Start* menu, instead of placing a folder (aka program group) in *Start* menu with the icon in it. May I know how to achieve this?

I don't want the *Start* menu to have uninstall shortcut either. To uninstall, I expect the user either right click the exe from *Start* Menu and select *"Uninstall"*, or go to program features to uninstall the app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create an icon in the top-level of the *Start* menu use the [`*programs` constants](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=autoprograms):

```
[Icons]
Name: "{autoprograms}\My Program"; Filename: "{app}\MyProgram.exe"
```

---

Inno Setup does not create any icons in the *Start* menu on its own, not even the uninstall icon. If your installer is creating the uninstaller icon, you must have an explicit entry in the `[Icons]` section for that. Remove it.

Though Windows 10 won't show such icons anyway:
[Inno Setup Start menu uninstall shortcut is not shown on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39371607/850848)